# How do i get string from Entry in tkinter? I use .get(), but it only returns 0

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have trouble returning results from Entry in tkinter. I do not use it immediately after creating tne Entry:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Enchantment generator')
window.geometry('800x600+400+300')
window.resizable(False, False)
window.entrylist = []
window.cbuttlist = []

res_lvl_mas = []
res_mas = []

def enchwind(chk_ench, ench, txt_ench, lvl_ench, ench_name, row, column):
    chk_ench = tk.BooleanVar()
    chk_ench.set(False)
    ench = tk.Checkbutton(window, text=ench_name, var=chk_ench)
    ench.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky='w')
    txt_ench = tk.Entry(window, width=3)
    txt_ench.grid(row=row, column=column+1)
    window.entrylist.append(txt_ench)
    window.cbuttlist.append(chk_ench)

def resstr(lvl, resmas):
    res = ''
    list = ['/give @p ', '{', 'Enchantments:[']
    for i in range(len(lvl)):
        list.append('{id:"minecraft:')
        list.append(resmas[i])
        list.append('",lvl:')
        list.append(lvl[i])
        if i != len(lvl) - 1:
            list.append('}, ')
        else:
            list.append('}')
    list.append(']}')
    for i in range(len(list)):
        res += list[i]
    return res

ench_mas = []
name_mas = ['Aqua affinity', 'Bane of arthropods', 'Binding curse', 'Blast protection',
            'Channeling', 'Depth strider', 'Efficiency', 'Feather falling', 'Fire aspect',
            'Fire protection', 'Flame', 'Fortune', 'Frost walker', 'Impaling', 'Infinity',
            'Knockback', 'Looting', 'Loyalty', 'Luck of the sea', 'Lure', 'Mending',
            'Power', 'Projective protection', 'Protection', 'Punch', 'Respiration',
            'Riptide', 'Sharpness', 'Silk touch', 'Smite', 'Sweeping', 'Thorns',
            'Unbreaking', 'Vanishing curse']

for i in range(34):
    ench_mas.append([])
for i in range(34):
    for j in range(7):
        ench_mas[i].append(0)
for i in range(34):
    ench_mas[i][4] = name_mas[i]
for i in range(17):
    ench_mas[i][5] = i+1
    ench_mas[i][6] = 0
for i in range(17, 34):
    ench_mas[i][5] = i-16
    ench_mas[i][6] = 2

ench_list = tk.Label(window, text='Choose the enchantments:')
ench_list.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4)

result = tk.Label(window, text='None')
result.grid(row=19, column=0, columnspan=4)

for i in range(34):
    enchwind(ench_mas[i][0], ench_mas[i][1], ench_mas[i][2], ench_mas[i][3], ench_mas[i][4], ench_mas[i][5], ench_mas[i][6])

def clicked():
    result.configure(text=txt)

for i in range(34):
    if window.cbuttlist[i].get():
        res_lvl_mas.append(window.entrylist[i].get())
        res_mas.append(ench_mas[i][4])

txt = resstr(res_lvl_mas, res_mas)

btn = tk.Button(window, text='Generate!', command=clicked)
btn.grid(column=0, row=18, columnspan=4)

window.mainloop()
```

This code creates commands for enchanting minecraft items. As you can see, i have 34 entrys so I decided to store their parameters as a list of lists. In the end of the program, when i wanted to get the numbers in entrys, it always returns 0. The interface looks like that: [Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRNJo.png).
I suppose those may be zeros left from first part of code, just to define list parameters.
Shoul i move something in the code or is it incorrect at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that you don't remember the Entry widgets. You just store them to a local variable in function `enchwind()` and don't store them anywhere. They are created but you lose all reference.

You could use a list as an attribute of `window` to store them:

In the definition of your window, add the line:

```
window.entrylist = []
```

Then, in our `enchwind()` function, you can store the Entry to this list:

```
    txt_ench = tk.Entry(window, width=3)
    txt_ench.grid(row=row, column=column+1)
    window.entrylist.append(txt_ench)
```

Now, you have a list of 34 items holding all your text Entries. You can access them by just getting the content of one of the elements of this list (i.e. `value = window.entrylist[5].get()` would get you the contents of the 6th Entry widget.

Comment: Thanks! After that, i got another problem - i need the program to add to final string only the entrys, near which checkbutton is situated. I used that construction:
```
for i in range(34):
    if window.entrylist[i].get() is not None:
        res_lvl_mas.append(window.entrylist[i].get())
        res_mas.append(ench_mas[i][4])
```
But it now returns all the enchantments, without levels.

Comment: I`ve kinda solved that (You can see how - ive edited the code) but now it came back to not returning anything at all

Comment: Ive tested it and found that `res_mas` and `res_lvl_mas` have nothing inside whatver i do in the gui

Comment: Indent your for-loop, which should fill `res_mas`. At the moment, it is only executed once at startup. Of course, it does not do anything. Indent it, so it is executed whenever you click. (and insert debug prints, i.e. `print(window.cbuttlist[i].get())` for each `i`, so you see what's in the checkboxes and when the loop gets executed.

Comment: Now it works! There are still some problems, but I`ll deal with it. Thanks!